# ArcGIS Server Object Extensions - Visual Studio Templates

Tags: server-object-extension, visual-studio

The  Visual Studio Templates for ArcGIS Server Object Extensions show up correctly in VS 2008, but not in VS2010.  Is there an easy way to resolve this?  Outside of copy and pasting code from VS2008 to VS2010.

Comment: They show up for me in VS2010, but only when I choose the .NET 3.5 framework in the dropdown listbox.

Comment: That worked, did you want to add it to the answers section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They show up for me in VS2010, but only when I choose the .NET 3.5 framework in the dropdown listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS Express, is it possible to change the .NET framework in this manner in Express or is it an option in the full product only?

Comment: I'm not sure.  If you create a new project in VS Express, is there a dropdown in the upper right hand corner to choose the version of .Net?