# ArcGIS Visual Studio IDE Integration Framework?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, .net

i need to integrate arcgis 9.3 with visual studio c# 2008 express edition.

i found the integration framework for 9.1 but no chance for 9.3 and i've seen a lot of questions on web about it.

What should i do to integrate?

the version of .net is 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar question about getting the integration to work with VS 2010:

[ArcGIS Server Object Extensions - Visual Studio Templates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/arcgis-server-object-extensions-visual-studio-templates)

Which version of the .Net framework are you using?  In this case it was working for 3.5, but not for 4.